# como hacer una consulta mysql donde coincida una parte del texto del campo?

Tags: php, html

espero alguien me ayude por favor. estoy tratando de hacer una consulta de mysql y php, tengo la tabla image, que realmente me guarda el nombre de archivos pdf y xml, pero quiero que cuando yo introduzca parte del nombre del archivo en un campo de texto y presione el boton de buscar, solo me muestre los archivos que tengan esa parte de texto en una tabla. pongo mi codigo para ver quien me puede ayudar porfa... gracias` 
este es el codigo donde quiero que se muestre la consulta

```
<?php 
session_start();
$varsesion = $_SESSION['usuario'];
if($varsesion==null || $varsesion='')
{
    echo'usted no tiene autorizacion';
    header("location:loguin_facturar.php");
die();
  }
?>
<?php
include "db.php";
$files = get_imgs_rfc();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Subir Multiples Imagenes y/o Archivos - By Evilnapsis</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Archivos</h1>
        <section  class="container" style="float:rigth; align: right;">
          <div class="col-md-8 "></div>   
          <form method="post" class="form-signin col-4" > 
              <p class="h6 mb-3 font-weight-normal" >Ingresa tu RFC para acceder a tus Facturas</p>
              <input  type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="RFC" required>
            <div class="space-20"></div>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm vervacantes btn-block"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Ver mis Facturas</button>

          </form>   
          <div class="col-4"></div> 

             </section >


        <?php if(count($files)>0):?>
            <br><table class="table">
            <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">fecha</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
            <?php foreach($files as $f):?>
                <tr>

                <td><?php echo $f->src;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->created_at;?></td>
                <td><a href="./download.php?id=<?php echo $f->id; ?>">Descargar</a></td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </table>
        <?php else:?>
            <h4>No hay archivos!</h4>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

y este es el archivo que hace las consultas...

```
/**
* Conexion a la base de datos y funciones
* 
**/

function con(){
    return new mysqli("localhost","root","","multi_upload");
}

function insert_img($folder, $image){
    $con = con();
    $con->query("insert into image (folder,src,created_at) value (\"$folder\",\"$image\",NOW())");
}
/*esta si funciona, pero me muestra todos los archivos que hay en la tabla*/
function get_imgs(){
    $images = array();
    $con = con();
    $query=$con->query("select * from image order by created_at desc");
    while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
        $images[] = $r;
    }
    return $images;
}

function get_img($id){
    $image = null;
    $con = con();
    $query=$con->query("select * from image where id=$id");
    while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
        $image = $r;
    }
    return $image;
}

function del($id){
    $con = con();
    $con->query("delete from image where id=$id");
}
/*esta es la que quiero que haga la consulta que contenga una parte del nombre del archivo*/

function get_imgs_rfc(){
    $images = array();
    $con = con();
    $query=$con->query("select * from image ");
    while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
        $images[] = $r;
    }
    return $images;
}

function get_img_rfc($id){
    $image = null;
    $con = con();
    $query=$con->query("select * from image where id=$id");
    while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
        $image = $r;
    }
    return $image;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer una query con la siguiente estructura:

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE src LIKE "%palabra%";
```

Tu función podría ser algo como:

```
function search_imgs($search){
    $images = array();
    $con = con();
    $query=$con->query('select * from image where src like "%'.$search.'%"');
    while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
        $images[] = $r;
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Finalmente cambiar:

```
$files = get_imgs_rfc();
```

por:

```
if(empty($_POST['name']))$files = get_imgs_rfc();
else $files = search_imgs($_POST['name']);
```

También, no sé si corresponde pero recomendaría que uses algún framework de desarrollo si estás haciendo un software de facturación (CakePHP, Yii, Codeigniter), te facilitará muchísimo los procesos.

¡Dime si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: pero al form donde tengo el campo donde se escribe parte del nombre, como le hago para mandar llamar esa función

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, espero te ayude

Comment: amigo, eres un genio, muchas gracias, ya quedo...

Comment: ¡Me alegra! Si puedes marcarla como correcta me ayudarías montón. ¡Éxito!